# Typedef with template parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

How can I solve this error?

My header file

```
template<typename T>
class C1 {
public:
typedef std::vector<T::F> TFV;
TFV Function1();
};
```

My CPP file

```
template<typename T>
TFV C1::Function() //error: ‘TFV’ does not name a type
{ }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, use the `typename` keyword to tell the compiler to interpret `F` as the (qualified) name of a type:

```
typedef std::vector<typename T::F> TFV;
//                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Secondly, `TFV` is not a type defined in the global namespace, so you have to properly qualify that as well in the definition of `Function1()`:

```
    template<typename T>
    typename C1<T>::TFV C1<T>::Function1()
//  ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^      ^^^
    { }
```

Finally, the definition of member functions of a class template should be placed in a *header file*, unless you are providing explicit instantiations for all the template instantiations you would otherwise implicitly generate.

Failing to do so will most likely result in an unresolved references error from the linker.

Comment: Thirdly, the definition needs to go in the header, unless it is instantiated for all desired types in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: @PeterWood: Correct. Let me mention that

Comment: Thanks for explaining with the step-wise clarity.

Answer (score 7):

Having C++11?  Then use trailing return types.

```
template<typename T>
class C1 {
public:
  typedef std::vector<typename T::F> TFV;
  TFV Function1();
};

template<typename T>
auto C1<T>::Function1() -> TFV { }
```

This works because after the parameters of the function, `()` in this case, the scope is the same as inside the `{}` block. You have access to `this` (useful in combination with decltype) and you can use `TFV` without the scope resolution operator.

Comment: Yes, I had read about trailing return type. Thanks. This simplifies the code to a very great extent. Thanks.